# How to create a new file with an existing emf resource

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm wondering how I can create a new file with an existing emf resource. At the moment I've the following code in my org.eclipse.ui.menus DefaultHandler, which get me the existing emf resource and create a new (empty) file:

```
if (element instanceof IResource) {
        IResource pldFile = (IResource) element;

    String path = pldFile.getLocation().toString();
    URI uri = URI.createFileURI(path);

    // Obtain a new resource set
    ResourceSet resSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    // Get the existing resource
    Resource emfResource = resSet.getResource(uri, true);

    IProject project = pldFile.getProject();
    String fileName = pldFile.getName().replace(pldFile.getFileExtension(), "plc");

    IFile plcFile = project.getFile(new Path(fileName));
    byte[] bytes = "".getBytes();
    try {
        InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        if (plcFile.exists()) {
            int i = 1;
            String tmp = "";
            do {
                    tmp = fileName;
                int index = tmp.indexOf(".plc");
                tmp = tmp.substring(0, index) + i + tmp.substring(index, tmp.length());
                plcFile = project.getFile(new Path(tmp));
                i++;
            } while (plcFile.exists());
            plcFile.create(source, IResource.NONE, null);
        } else {
            plcFile.create(source, IResource.NONE, null);
        }
        PlcEditorInput input = new PlcEditorInput(emfResource);
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        IDE.openEditor(page, plcFile);      
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I assign now the existing emf resource to my newly created file?

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to import the resource as new file. I mean define a new file or project  and then import the resource. 
To be honestly I try a similary way but it didn't work with my resource(--> it's a 10-years-old-code).